# ArcObjects interface to construct circles with segments instead of arcs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, vb.net, add-in

I am trying to see if it is feasible, using ArcObjects (VB.NET), to create a tool to construct circles comprised of line segments instead of arcs.  I've looked over the available interfaces [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IConstructCircularArc_Interface/002m000000qw000000/) but do not see one for the task.

Is anyone aware of an interface to make this fairly straight forward?

Comment: You could generalize the circular arc geometry. This will create straight segments.

Comment: Usually folks are worried about the other direction (preserving perfect curves).  It's far *easier* to generate an array of vertices (WKSPoint) and populate a Polygon, and the documentation has [examples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000002wm000000.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're after is [IPolycurve.Generalize](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/d/002m000002m5000000.htm). This will turn an arc into a series of straight segments approximating the line. This interface is implemented by both polygon and polyline.

Use a simple buffer of a point ([ITopologicalOperator.Buffer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Buffer_Method/002m000003v8000000/)) for a circle (or create a circular arc circle with [IConstructCircularArc.ConstructCircle](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ConstructCircle_Method/002m000000rr000000/)) cast to IPolycurve and then Generalize. You will need to enter parameters for stroking the line, they should be a function of the radius/buffer distance.

There is no code in your question so I can't help with a code sample of how to integrate this into your code.

I think a Circular Arc is a primitive type (like a segment) and needs to be incorporated into a polyline (via [ISegmentCollection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000035r000000)) to cast to an IPolyCurve.. perhaps.. IPolyCurve inherits ICurve which is implemented by CircularArc so perhaps you could cast directly.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the circumcircle of a triangle. The circumcircle of a triangle is the circle that passes through all three vertices of the triangle and is unique. [**Help**](http://www.mathopenref.com/constcircumcircle.html)

Although I think you are not looking for the math behind, [**here**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcircle.html), you can find the math to reach to center and radius of a circumcircle from three points (a triangle).

The good news is that ArcObjects has interface to calculate a circumcircle. It is located in TIN related assemblies which is **ITinTriangle.QueryCircumCircle**

To use this interface you should first create an in-memory TIN:

Here is a C# code. This code is not tested and may have runtime errors

```cs
// Instantiate a new empty TIN.
ITinEdit TinEdit = new TinClass();

// Initialize the TIN with an envelope. The envelope's extent should be set large enough to 
// encompass all the data that will be added to the TIN. The envelope's spatial reference, if
// if has one, will be used as the TIN's spatial reference. If it is not set, as in this case,
// the TIN's spatial reference will be unknown.
IEnvelope Env = new EnvelopeClass();
Env.PutCoords(0, 0, 10, 10);
TinEdit.InitNew(Env);

// Add points to the TIN. These will become triangle nodes.
IPoint Point = new PointClass();
Point.X = 2;
Point.Y = 2;
Point.Z = 0;
TinEdit.AddPointZ(Point, 0);

Point.Y = 7;
TinEdit.AddPointZ(Point, 0);

Point.X = 7;
TinEdit.AddPointZ(Point, 0);

var tinAdv = TinEdit as ITinAdvanced;
var tri = tinAdv.GetTriangle(0);

IPoint pt = new PointClass();
double r = 0;

tri.QueryCircumCircle(pt, r);
```

Sorry, I don't know VB.NET, use code converters to convert it.

Comment: That's a pretty exotic solution; you should probably mention it's implemented in Python and requires 3D Analyst.

Comment: Oh I Didn't know it's implemented in python!

Comment: No, I take than back; it's C#, not Python.  But you should specify the language if you're not going to use the requested one.